# what does with open do in this situation

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
s=sentence.split()
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]
print(sentence)
print(positions)
with open('task_2.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(positions))
    f.write(str(sentence))
f.close()
```

In this task I must develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of the word in the list. It must then compress the positions and send it to a file. I have managed to complete all of the above but im struggling to understand the "with open" part. I have tried just using "open" and the code comes up with a syntax error. So if anyone could explain to me what  the keyword "with" does in this situation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: try google, it's fun

Comment: `f.close()` is redundant in your code. Because of `with`.

Comment: i have but im still struggling to understand. I dont have a lot of knowledge using python, sorry

Comment: Well my comment gets you part way. It's the context manager. In this case with a file, it's automatically closing the file for you once all of the operations are complete.

Comment: @joe this is much less about python than it is about finding basic stuff. Googling for "python with open" returns at least three pages on the first page that make perfectly clear what that construct does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with open('task_2.json', 'w') as f:` closes the file after the indented code runs. This means that you don't need the `f.close()` line. Using a `with` statement in python is just a safer way to work with files.

Answer (score 0):

`with` in this case creates a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) that will `close()` your file object automatically when the indented code under `with` finishes. For example:

```
with open('task_2.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(positions))
    f.write(str(sentence))

print(f.closed)
```

will print `True`, while:

```
f = open('task_2.json', 'w')
f.write(str(positions))
f.write(str(sentence))
print(f.closed)
```

Will print `False`, and the file will need to be closed manually with `f.close()` to free up system resources.

Comment: The syntax error will come from the fact that OP simply tried to remove `with` leaving `open('task_2.json', 'w') as f:`

Comment: @roganjosh just reread question. Didn't realize OP had tried to do that...Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @TimCastelijns opened my mouth without testing it first. Thanks for pointing that out. Removed that comment.

Comment: Something I've often wondered is why it _doesn't_ throw an error when you explicitly `close()` a file handled by `with`.

Comment: @roganjosh yeah good point. If you call other methods on it, it will raise an exception. I couldn't find an explanation in more recent documentation, but these older docs simply mention that you can call `.close()` on a file more than once (without explaining why): https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html. Maybe to prevent errors caused by the file being closed elsewhere and then trying to close it again?

Comment: That's an interesting link. If all other operations will fail anyway, then what's the purpose of allowing you to call `close()` twice? Surely you're more likely to get an error from any other operation than `close()`

Comment: @roganjosh https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close describes the ability to call `close()` multiple times as a "convinience", but I can't think of a situation where it would be convenient.