# Why can you close() a file object more than once?

Tags: python

This question is purely out of curiosity. Brought up in a recent discussion for a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599926/what-does-with-open-do-in-this-situation/39600026?noredirect=1#39600026), I've often wondered why the context manager (`with`) does not throw an error when people explicitly close the file anyway through misunderstanding... and then I found that you can call `close()` on a file multiple times with no error even without using `with`.

The only thing we can find relating to this is [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) and it just blandly says (emphasis mine):

> close(    ) 
>   Close the file. A closed file cannot be read or written any more. Any operation which requires that the file be open will raise a ValueError after the file has been closed. **Calling close() more than once is allowed**.

It would appear that this is intentional by design but, if you can't perform any operations on the closed file without an exception, we can't work out why closing the file multiple times is permitted. Is there a use case?

Comment: Maybe if the code was a bit sloppy, and had `close()` in multiple places rather than tracking the state of the file throughout... at least your code wouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: Ha! You beat me to it! I am in the middle of composing an almost identical question, and just saw this pop up as a related question. I will upvote instead ;)

Comment: @elethan I was just about to message you in the other thread :P

Comment: Sometimes it makes code a little bit easier. Also, if you had an actual bug where you `close` a file and later use it again *the other operations would already trigger an exception*. So there's really no point in triggering it there too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Thinking about `with` is just wrong. This behaviour has been in Python *forever* and thus it's worth keeping it for backward compatibility.
2. Because it would serve no purpose to raise an exception. If you have an actual bug in your code where you might close the file before finishing using it, you'll get an exception when using the `read` or `write` operations anyway, and thus you'll never reach the second call to `close`.
3. Allowing this will *rarely* make the code easier to write avoiding adding lots of `if not the_file.isclosed(): the_file.close()`.
4. The BDFL designed the file objects in that way and we are stuck with that behaviour since there's no strong reason to change it.

Comment: `the_file.closed` ;)

Comment: Idempotent closing of files is just a good idea. Since calling close() multiple times is *not* an error, the programmer will ideally become more aggressive when cleaning up resources.  As @Bakuriu mentions, checking if the file is closed or not (to avoid an error) before closing just complicates code and annoys the programmer.

Answer (score 6):

Resource management is a big deal.  It's part of the reason why we have context managers in the first place.

I'm *guessing* that the core development team thought that it is better to make it "safe" to call close more than once to encourage people to close their files.  Otherwise, you could get yourself into a situation where you're asking "Was this closed before?".  If `.close()` couldn't be called multiple times, the only option would be to put your `file.close()` call in a `try`/`except` clause.  That makes the code uglier and (frankly), lots of people probably would just delete the call to `file.close()` rather than handle it properly.  In this case, it's just convenient to be able to call `file.close()` without worrying about any consequences since it's almost certain to succeed and leave you with a file that you know is closed afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Function call fulfilled its promise - after calling it file **is closed**. It's not like something *failed*, it's just you did not have to do anything at all to ensure condition you we're asking for.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. I was asking more along the lines of calling `close()` on something that is already closed would usually result in an exception, but it doesn't in the case of a closed file object

Comment: @roganjosh is it? should `dict_instance.clear()` raise an exception if dict was already empty (because "there is nothing to clear")? Instance will be empty after function call and that's all what caller asks for. Sometimes doing nothing is enough to make a test pass.  Also, what is your source on _it would usually result in an exception_?

Comment: I'm not sure where this is going, the other answers were pretty clear. Try closing a cursor on a closed connection to an `sqlite3` database. You're saying that it's not unusual to be able to do _nothing_ to a `closed` object other than to `close()` it a second time?